# Make Mollweide oval

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers

On base of this [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281615/reproject-xyz-tilelayer-to-mollweide) i have a map with xyz-tilelayers in Mollweide projection.
Now, the tilelayer is presented in rectangular form, parts of the world are duplicated and presented in a very distorted manner:
[image]
How do i achieve the typical oval form of Mollweide?

Comment: Maybe one of the following questions give you a hint: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/185881/8673 https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/281164/8673